# Konjunktiv II in der Vergangenheit

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive, perfect-tense, auxiliary-verb

This is the answer given to a question in my Grammatiktrainer:

> Hätte ich keinen Unfall gehabt, hätte ich in Urlaub fahren können.

My question is this: Why isn't "wäre" used in the second clause seeing as "fahren" uses "sein" as the auxiliary when forming the Perfekt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because *hätte* does not refer to *fahren* but to *können*. In the second clause (which is actually the main clause), *können* is an *Ersatzinfintiv* which plays the role of a perfect participle.

So without *können* it's

> Ich wäre gefahren.

but with *können* it's

> Ich hätte fahren können.

Comment: Note that *hätte … können* is the main clause, not the subordinate clause.

Comment: That's right, I corrected my answer.